# Capturing queue/channel information using Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following requirement: 
A message could come in on one of several message-driven-channel-adapter definitions, all obviously mapped to different incoming queues.

All the channel adapters then forward to the same internal Spring Integration channel  where they are handled.

How can it be determined exactly which channel adapter - and therefore queue - the message was received on? For instance, is there a way in the channel adapter configuration to specify that a property be added to the message header at that point, which would be one solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to write a ChannelInterceptor to add a header to the message. The preSend() method provides the Message and MessageChannel as arguments. MessageChannel may be cast to NamedComponent (An interface implemented be AbstracMessageChannel) to get the channel name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [header enrichier](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html) with a different identifier after each message-driven-channel-adapter.

For example :

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn1" destination="inQueue1" channel="in1"/>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="in1" output-channel="out1">
     <int:header name="fromAdapter" value="1"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn2" destination="inQueue2" channel="in1"/>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="in2" output-channel="out2">
     <int:header name="fromAdapter" value="2"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I see a problem here. This solution will only work if each message-driven-channel-adapter forwards to a different channel (which the header-enricher can then link to). But in my scenario they all channel-adapters forward to the same internal channel. Is there any other way of configuring the header-enricher. Of course one could just create another layer of internal channels, but wondered if you have any other ideas.

Comment: This is an error in my code sample. You can use the same output channel for the both message driven channel adapters. And then you can use the header value in order to know where your messages comes from.

Comment: Thanks, but am still not clear. How do you associate the header enricher with the adapter without using the output channel of the adapter to link them? Could you provide another code snippet?

Comment: hi. You can use the same output channel for the both message channel adapter output. I edited my code sample to fit it.